# How to install OpenGl and SDL2 libraries on ubuntu

Tags: command-line, opengl

I am trying to build Cube2 Sauerbraten, But I need the OpenGL and SDL2 libraries to run the makefile. (I am using ubuntu here) I tried running `sudo apt-get install --yes software-properties-common g++ make` then `sudo apt-get install --yes libsdl2-dev` then `sudo apt-get install --yes freeglut3-dev` and lastly, to compile, `g++ main.cpp -I /usr/include/SDL2/ -lSDL2  -lGL`.

I got these commands from https://gist.github.com/dirkk0/cad259e6a3965abb4178.  When I run them, the first three commands work fine, but the last one did not work, giving me this error.

```
optiplex780@super-OptiPlex-780:~$ g++ main.cpp -I /usr/include/SDL2/ -lSDL2  -lGL
cc1plus: fatal error: main.cpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
optiplex780@super-OptiPlex-780:~$
```

Should I replace main.cpp with the makefile?

Am I just a dunce, or is there a problem here?  After installing the packages, I tried going to the `~/sauerbraten/src` dorectory, and running `make install`.  I got these errors.

```
optiplex780@super-OptiPlex-780:~/sauerbraten_2020_12_29_linux/sauerbraten/src$ make install
make    -C enet/ all
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/optiplex780/sauerbraten_2020_12_29_linux/sauerbraten/src/enet'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/optiplex780/sauerbraten_2020_12_29_linux/sauerbraten/src/enet'
g++ -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Wall -fsigned-char -o sauer_client shared/crypto.o shared/geom.o shared/stream.o shared/tools.o shared/zip.o engine/3dgui.o engine/bih.o engine/blend.o engine/blob.o engine/client.o engine/command.o engine/console.o engine/cubeloader.o engine/decal.o engine/dynlight.o engine/glare.o engine/grass.o engine/lightmap.o engine/main.o engine/material.o engine/menus.o engine/movie.o engine/normal.o engine/octa.o engine/octaedit.o engine/octarender.o engine/physics.o engine/pvs.o engine/rendergl.o engine/rendermodel.o engine/renderparticles.o engine/rendersky.o engine/rendertext.o engine/renderva.o engine/server.o engine/serverbrowser.o engine/shader.o engine/shadowmap.o engine/sound.o engine/texture.o engine/water.o engine/world.o engine/worldio.o fpsgame/ai.o fpsgame/client.o fpsgame/entities.o fpsgame/fps.o fpsgame/monster.o fpsgame/movable.o fpsgame/render.o fpsgame/scoreboard.o fpsgame/server.o fpsgame/waypoint.o fpsgame/weapon.o -Lenet/.libs -lenet -L/usr/X11R6/lib `sdl-config --libs` -lSDL_image -lSDL_mixer -lz -lGL -lrt
/bin/sh: 1: sdl-config: not found
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL_image
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lSDL_mixer
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:163: client] Error 1
optiplex780@super-OptiPlex-780:~/sauerbraten_2020_12_29_linux/sauerbraten/src$
```

Comment: "I need the OpenGL" : `sudo apt install libglvnd-dev`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program has many files, then a single `g++` won’t be enough. A `make` (No arguments) command is often the right way to compile the software from the Makefile.

The Makefile is in the `src` folder… you should enter it (`cd src`) before launching `make`. `make install` compile the software if not done and install it.

According to the readme_source.txt file, it uses zlib, then the `zlib1g-dev` package will be helpful. Also `libsdl-mixer1.2-dev` and `libsdl-image1.2-dev` (On a Debian system, the actual version may vary. You seem to have a 2 version).

Comment: I successfully did it with the makefile once before, and it worked, but I don't remember what I did.  I did not use zlib though.

Comment: @steeldriver : yes (of course). Corrected.

Comment: I have seen your edit… and added two packages in my answer which should be needed too.

Comment: OK.  The `libsdl-image1.2-dev` package was found, but the `libsdl1.2-mixer-dev` package was not found or installed.  The error message it gives me says it's only missing the mixer package, but It can find the image package. The zlib package was already insatalled.

Comment: Type `apt list libsdl\*-dev` And see which SDL related dev packages are available.

Comment: It was libsdl2-mixer1.2-dev  thaks :)